# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el proyecto de visual studio desde iis?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis

El problema es que no tengo el proyecto de visual studio de una aplicación y me piden que haga cambios en ella. Lo único a lo que tengo acceso es al servidor en donde está publicada la aplicación pero en este no sale la solución ni los archivos .cs. ¿Que podría hacer?

Comment: no se puede, ya que segun explicas no tienes el codigo, lo maximo que podrias cambiar es algo del html si editas el aspx, pero el .cs se compila por lo tanto no se puede cambiar sino tienes el codigo

Comment: ¿Has revisado esos archivos?. Es posible publicar asp.net que se compile al momento de arrancar, en caso de que no haya ningún archivo legible y sólo compilados pues lo natural es que vuelvas a preguntar dónde está el código

Answer (score 1):

Me encontré en esa situación hace años, lo que puedes hacer es descompilar y armar de nuevo el proyecto, para esto puedes usar una herramienta como [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/), que hasta puede generar un proyecto de Visual Studio a partir de un archivo dll.

Ten en cuenta que el código que la herramienta genere no necesariamente sea muy legible, pero en la mayoría de los casos es suficiente para comenzar.

Si no tienes el código fuente y nadie te lo puede proveer, esta es la siguiente mejor opción.